# How to prevent Python + PySerial from reading the wrong starting byte

Tags: python, hex, pyserial, uart

So I am currently dealing with a slight problem with Python 3 and PySerial. I have a Raspberry Pi along with a Control Box linked up via the UART ports on the RPI. The controlbox sends data to the raspberry pi every 50ms and I want to read that data so I can use a parser to grab some needed data from it. The only issue is when I try to read data, the starting hex value is incorrect because I am starting to read data halfway the feedback being sent back by the controlbox.

For example:

```
b'\x21\x21\x22\x98\x98\x24\x23\x21\x21\x22\x22\x98
```

I need the x98 (0x98) to be the starting hex value for that byte so it looks like this

```
x98\x98\x24\x23\x21\x21\x22\x22\
```

I need to have it like this so I can grab a certain hex code (from the byte) such as x21 and use that for my program. I have done research and haven't been able to come up with a single thing. What should I do to make this possible?

Comment: You should buffer the bytes read and split them on the start marking bytes.

Comment: I did research on buffering the bytes on python and the closest I got                 is [python struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). I have no idea how to do this. May I please have a quick example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function, preferably threaded, that reads from the serial port and puts the data into a queue. Then you get the bytes one at a time from the queue and do what you want to do with that data.

```
import serial
import _thread as thread
import queue

serialport = serial.Serial('COM1')
queue_in = queue.Queue()

def run_serial_input():
    input = serialport.readall()
    for byte in input:
        queue_in.put(byte)

thread.start_new_thread(run_serial_input(), ())

while True:
    # Do things with your bytes....
    byte = queue_in.get()
    if byte == 0x98:
        pass
```